# Extract string between another string and a character (PowerShell)

Tags: string, powershell, substring, character, extract

I am programming with PowerShell for the first time and not very comfortable with it.
I have a file containing many lines like this one "AddItems failed for tag ABCDEFGH, type VT_R4: The ItemID is not in the server address space (c0040007)".
I would like to retrieve only the ABCDEFGH string. I tried `.Substring()` method first but it does not really work, since all Strings I am trying to retrieve do not have the same length. The idea would basically be to take out every string contained between "tag" and ",", but I do not know how to code that.

```
$log = get-content C:\Logs\mylog.txt
foreach ($line in $log) { 
    if ($line -like "*tag*") {
        $line.substring(24,36)
        $line | out-file -FilePath "C:\Logs\ItemIDs.txt" -Append
    }
}
```

Here below an example of an input :

```
tag Z..ANTW@ENERGY@C605_RAIL4_MC_403
tag ANTW@CALI@CALLISTO@130LI513B.PV,
```

`Z..ANTW@ENERGY@C605_RAIL4_MC_403` and `ANTW@CALI@CALLISTO@130LI513B.PV` both being the ABCDEFGH, furthermore there are few letters missing for the first example.

Thank you very much for your help, it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: if your abcdef is general, you have to show the the tag before and after..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-match` regex operator to test whether a given string contains a certain pattern, then use the `$Matches` automatic variable to extract any groups captured:

```
if('tag ANTW@CALI@CALLISTO@130LI513B.PV,' -match 'tag ([^,]+),'){
    $Matches[1] 
}
```

You'll find the output from the above statement to be the string `ANTW@CALI@CALLISTO@130LI513B.PV`, so assuming that's all you need, just output to add it to your loop and output `$Matches[1]` to the file:

```
foreach($line in $log){
    if($line -match 'tag ([^,]+),'){
        $Matches[1] |Out-File -FilePath C:\Logs\ItemIDs.txt -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not know about Regex but your method worked great! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure we could find permutations and combinations of simple string methods like `.SubString()` and `.IndexOf()` to get this right, but doing so always requires a reliable degree of consistency in the input strings.  That said, working with the example you gave:

```
$String = "AddItems failed for tag ABCDEFGH, type VT_R4: The ItemID is not in the server address space (c0040007)"

$OutputString = $String.SubString($String.IndexOf("tag")+4)
$OutputString = ($OutputString -split ',')[0]
```

This assumes the word "tag" always precedes "ABCDEFGH" and the "," always trails it. and says find the start position of tag add 4 to it. Then use `-split` to get an array, but only give me the first element which should be anything to the left of ",".

However and similar to [Mathias's characteristically good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67507227/4749264), I think RegEx is a better match for this (no pun intended).  However, I like the use of look-arounds for this:

I don't know if this is perfect, maybe it can be refined.  I don't consider myself a RegEx expert...

```
$String = "AddItems failed for tag ABCDEFGH, type VT_R4: The ItemID is not in the server address space (c0040007)"
$String -match "(?!tag)\w*(?=,)"
```

This should return: `ABCDEFGH`.

In short this means return the text found between "tag" and ",".

Bringing it together with your original code:

```
$log     = Get-Content 'C:\Logs\mylog.txt'
$pattern = '(?<=tag\s{1}).*(?=\,)'

ForEach ($line in $log) { 
    if ( $line -match $pattern ) {
        $Matches[0] | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Logs\ItemIDs.txt" -Append
    }
}
```